How many state keys are too many?
The Drupal Core release 10.3 has a change in settings files, which recommends state_cache to be set to true unless there are too many. If it's not set, this is the message that shows up in Status Report

STATE CACHE FLAG NOT SET -- State cache flag settings['state_cache'] is not set. It is recommended to be set to TRUE in settings.php unless there are too many state keys. Drupal 11 will default to having state cache enabled.

I know the table involved -- key_value and can see the number of items. I'm guessing that my site might have too many (comparing a couple of sites of mine), but how would I know? The large number seems to be largely related to pathauto (there's some suggestion at least that this is maybe not the best place for it https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto/issues/3422136)
And if I do have "too many" what is the repercussion? would it be good to reduce that number? and what would a good goal be?

Okay, I looked a little harder and found this reference
https://www.drupal.org/node/3177901
To find the number of items involved:
SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(LENGTH(value)) FROM key_value WHERE collection = 'state';

Furthermore, the article states: "sites with more than 100 entries and/or a total value size/length of 100,000 should review their specific entries using the following query and either optimize their usage or disable state caching as a temporary measure."
So the not everything in the key_value table is relevant to the question, which is good news. Since the SELECT count returned fewer than I was otherwise expecting.
